How do I include a cmake target as a dependency in a py_library target? (tiny-cuda-nn)
I'm trying to wrap tiny-cuda-nn with bazel to include as a dependency for other projects. This is a cmake project, but it has bindings for Python. The conventional way to install this would be with a pip command:
pip install git+https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/#subdirectory=bindings/torch

I'm trying to clone the repo, build cmake project, and then use the python files in the py_library. In my WORKSPACE.bazel file, I get the repo:
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "new_git_repository")

_ALL_CONTENT = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""

new_git_repository(
    name = "tinycudann_repo",
    branch = "master",
    build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
    recursive_init_submodules = True,
    remote = "git@github.com:NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn.git",
)

I have a BUILD.bazel file located in ./third_party/tinycudann, which has:
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")

# Update requirements based on requirements_lock.in
compile_pip_requirements(
    name = "requirements_lock",
    src = "requirements_lock.in",
    requirements_txt = "requirements_lock.txt",
)

load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_library")
load("@pip_deps_nerfstudio//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

# First, build tinycudann.
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cmake(
    name = "built_and_installed_tinycudann",
    install = True,
    lib_source = "@tinycudann_repo//:all_srcs",
    out_binaries = [
        "mlp_learning_an_image",
        "bench_image_ours",
    ],
    out_static_libs = [
        "libtiny-cuda-nn.a",
    ],
)

py_library(
    name = "tinycudann_py_lib",
    srcs = ["@tinycudann_repo//:all_srcs"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":built_and_installed_tinycudann",
        requirement("torch"),
    ],
)

There is a requirements_lock.in file that only has torch==2.4.0 inside, and a requirements_lock.txt that is generated when I run bazel run //third_party/tinycudann:requirements_lock.update.
That's pretty much it. I'm expecting other python scripts will add
deps = [
    "//third_party/tinycudann:tinycudann_py_lib",
]

if they need to use this.
I am expecting the build time on first compilation to be about 15 minutes. If I run bazel build //third_party/tinycudann:built_and_installed_tinycudann then the clock starts running up and I can tell that it's doing something.
If I run bazel build //third_party/tinycudann:tinycudann_py_lib, though, it finishes in about a second. I know that it's not compiling anything. When I run the downstream script target that references this as an input, it complains AttributeError: module 'tinycudann' has no attribute 'Encoding'.
So I have two primary concerns here:

Somehow the cmake target isn't getting built when I reference tinycudann_py_lib, even though it is given as a dependency to that lib, and
A py_library may not be the correct way to use the built cmake project, even if I could build it. I have seen pip_parse but it looks like that all revolves around the requirements_lock files, and I can't put the full URL in with a subfolder target. Later in the documentation, under "Using third party packages as dependencies," there is an example that seems to show using py_library exactly as I have it above.


Here's an example python binding being exported as a python library. Pasting it here:
# Adapted from: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1475
cc_binary(
  name = "binding.so",
  srcs = ["binding.cpp"],
  copts = ["-I/usr/include/python3.5/"],
  linkshared = 1,
  linkstatic = 1,
  deps = [
    "@pybind11//:pybind11",
    "//native"
  ],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

py_library(
  name = 'binding',
  data=[':binding.so'],
  imports=['.'],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

Basically, you want a Python library which accesses the native library as data, then I think it can be used as a dep as you expect.

This helped in that using the data field in the py_library command triggered the cmake project to build, but it still failed to work. When I referenced my tinycudann_py_lib in the deps for the project that needs it, I get messages (from the bazelified script, not bazel) that it's not found. I believe it should be exposed to pip for Python to recognize it, and that led me eventually to this post, in the rules_python github project, asking how to have local files referenced in a pip_parse, and the answer is it's not possible.
